# page opening even if not logged in, Django

Tags: python, django

I have made a small project.

User first logs in then he is redirected to the home page.

But if a user has not logged in then also that homepage is opening if we paste the url of that home page.

I have tried many things given on net but it's not working.

This is my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from blog import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^register/$', views.register, name='register'),
    url(r'^home/$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^javaq/$', views.javaq, name='javaq'),
    url(r'^javar/$', views.javar, name='javar'),
    url(r'^csq/$', views.csq, name='csq'),

    url(r'^csr/$', views.csr, name='csr'),
    url(r'^cq/$', views.cq, name='cq'),
    url(r'^cr/$', views.cr, name='cr'),
    url(r'^cppq/$', views.cppq, name='cppq'),
    url(r'^cppr/$', views.cppr, name='cppr'),
    url(r'^pythonq/$', views.pythonq, name='pythonq'),
    url(r'^pythonr/$', views.pythonr, name='pythonr'),
    url(r'^mini/$', views.mini, name='mini'),
]
```

This is my view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import logininfo,CSTEST,CTEST,CPPTEST,JAVATEST,PYTHONTEST,result
from django.http import HttpResponse

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_control

import datetime


def login(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        user_name=request.POST.get("username")
        sid=request.POST.get("sid")
        password=request.POST.get("password")
        article = logininfo()
        article.user_name = user_name
        article.sid = sid
        article.password = password
        article.save()

    return render(request,'login.html')

def home(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        sid=request.POST.get("sid")
        password=request.POST.get("password")

        request.session['sd'] = sid 
        user_obj=logininfo.objects.filter(sid=sid,password=password)
        if user_obj.count()==0:
            return HttpResponse("Sorry wrong password try again")
    return render(request,'home.html')  

def register(request):
    return render(request,'register.html')

def javaq(request):
    context = {
        'query_results' : JAVATEST.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'javaq.html',context)


def javar(request):

    if request.method=="POST":
        chosenOption = ''
        correctAns = ''
        c=0
        x=1

        for ans in JAVATEST.objects.all():
            chosenOption=str(request.POST.get("java"+str(x)))
            correctAns=str(ans.ANSWER)

            if chosenOption==correctAns:
                c=c+1
            x=x+1
        article = result()
        article.sid = request.session['sd']

        article.marks = c
        article.subject = 'JAVA'
        article.tdate = str(datetime.datetime.now())
        article.save()    
        context = {
            'query_results1' :c

        }

    return render(request, 'javar.html',context)
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator

Comment: you can use decorator...Try it .

Comment: @floydya i have tried that but it's not working.I don't know where i am doing mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the @login_required decorator to your view function (the ones that render the pages that shouldn't appear to non logged in users).

You can have a broader idea about this decorator in [this page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.1/topics/auth/default/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use django built-in login-authentication on pages

```
@login_required(login_url='/url where you want user to redirect/') 
def myview(request):
    do something
    return something #returns when user is logged in
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should take a look at [Django Stronghold](https://github.com/mgrouchy/django-stronghold).

Enable this in your settings, as per the instructions, and every view becomes private by default.

You can then decorate any functions which you want public access to like this:

```
@public
def register():
    # Do something
```

This is probably the way to go for a beginner, as what you're doing just now (handling authentication logic in the home view) means you'll be repeating this for each separate view, and if you miss something, private parts of the app could end up public.